# Is there a name for the reciprocal of the fractional part of a number?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, ceiling-and-floor-functions, continued-fractions, fractional-part

Define a partial function $$f : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$$ as follows: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

If I understand correctly, the numbers occuring in the continued fraction expansion of an irrational number $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ can be expressed succinctly as

$$(\lfloor x \rfloor,\lfloor fx \rfloor,\lfloor ffx \rfloor, \lfloor fffx \rfloor,\ldots)$$

It would therefore be convenient if there were an accepted name or notation for this function.

> **Question.** Is there?

Comment: It looks a bit similar to [Gauss map](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/magic/lecture01.pdf), but I'm afraid that it's not it.